# Настроить yii2 на linux

Tags: linux, yii2

У меня не получается чтобы, сайт выводил из фреймворка yii2. Я примерно реализовывал виртуальный хост для yii2 следующие действие
Сам проект yii2 у меня находится в директории `var/www/html/trainingYii`. Только там символическая ссылка стоит.
Потом я создал файл в директории `/etc/apache2/sites-available/yii2-app.conf`
И в нем прописал

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName yii2-app
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/trainingYii

         <Directory /var/www/html/trainingYii>
        Options Indexes FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/www/yii2-app/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/yii2-app/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

И делаю символическую ссылку
    sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/yii2-app.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/yii2-app.conf
Получаю ссылку и потом я в `/etc/hosts` вписал `127.0.0.1   yii2-app`
И потом я перезарузил apache2 и получил вот такой ответ

```
ruslan@debian:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ sudo service apache2 restart
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Посмотрел в логах в чем причина

```
[Sat Feb 10 12:52:58.622686 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7009] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

Как мне сделать виртуальный хост для yii2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример для backend, у тебя ошибка там в apache конфиге.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName yii2-app
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/trainingYii/backend/web
    <Directory "/var/www/html/trainingYii/">
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_trainingYii_backend.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_trainingYii_backend.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Потом делаешь

```
sudo a2ensite yii2-app.conf
sudo service apache2 reload
```